# What is this knitr magic that produces a plot by calling <<plot_this>>?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to work out how [this report](http://www.slate.com/features/pkremp_forecast/report.html)  on a STAN model for the 2016 US presidential elections is generated using `rmarkdown`:

[image]

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pkremp/polls/master/report.Rmd

I have looked at the source code available on [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pkremp/polls/master/report.Rmd), which contains lines like:

````
# Electoral College 

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, fig.align='center'}
<<plot_ev>>
```
````

The command `<<plot_ev>>` seems to generate plots from code in [graphs.R](https://github.com/pkremp/polls/blob/master/graphs.R):

```
# Not accounting for the EV allocation rules of Nebraska and Maine

# @knitr plot_ev

ggplot() + 
    geom_histogram(data = data.frame(ev = result_ev_all_states), aes(ev, fill = ifelse(ev >= 270,"Clinton","Trump")), binwidth = 1) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#6E90F8", "#FF6666"), guide = guide_legend(title = "Winner")) +
    xlab("Electoral Votes for Clinton") + 
    theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.line.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
    ggtitle(paste("EV distribution - Pr(Clinton wins) = ", round(mean(result_ev_all_states >= 270)*100, 0), "%", sep = ""))
```

How does this work?

Comment: my guess: undocumented association of [externalization](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/) and old sweave syntax.

Comment: What I don't understand is why is it necessary to have this, when you could wrap it in a normal function that returns a plot?

Comment: code externalisation is all about providing the flexibility of a slightly different workflow. Having the code in a separate self-contained R file can be useful to run the code step-by-step, which is typically easier when things are not wrapped in functions. But sure, you could do that too. I can't speak for this particular example (and I don't think the `<<>>` syntax is fully correct nowadays), but another thing to consider is that each chunk can return multiple plots, echo multiple lines of code, results, etc. which would be harder with a single function call as chunk body.

Comment: No, it is not externalization, but chunk references instead: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/ The point is to reuse code chunks.