# What is the difference between knitr ```{} chunks and <<>> chunks?

Tags: r, knitr

I have seen both angled brackets:

```
<<>>= 
...
@
```

and back ticks:

````
```{}
...
```
````

used to indicate 'chunks' in the knitr documentation. What is the difference between these two?

For example, can I replace the following block of code from the [documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/minimal/):

```
<<my-label, eval=TRUE, dev='png'>>=
set.seed(1213)  # for reproducibility
x = cumsum(rnorm(100))
mean(x)  # mean of x
plot(x, type = 'l')  # Brownian motion
@
```

with:

````
```{r my-label}
set.seed(1213)  # for reproducibility
x = cumsum(rnorm(100))
mean(x)  # mean of x
plot(x, type = 'l')  # Brownian motion
```
````

Answer (score 4):

The backtick syntax is used in Rmarkdown documents (Markdown mixed with R code: usually stored as file extension `.rmd`), while the angle-bracket syntax is used in documents that mix LaTeX with R code (usually stored as `.Rnw`). I'm not sure what to call the latter; they used to be "Sweave documents", but the `Sweave` package has been largely superseded by the `knitr` package.  However, `knitr` (and the `rmarkdown` package) can both process both markdown+R and LaTeX+R documents ...

Your suggested substitution of

````
```{r chunklabel,..options..}
...
```
````

for

```
<<chunklabel,..options..>>=
...
@
```

seems reasonable (and very easy to just try it out!)  Of course, you will need to make sure that the `knitr`/`rmarkdown` tools you're using know what syntax type you're starting with. `knitr::knit` seems (based on docs) to guess from the file extension. The docs for `rmarkdown::render` only talk about `.rmd`.

The easiest way to figure all this out is probably just to do a few experiments.

Comment: thanks. so I am guessing I can interchange the `<<>> ... @` code here: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/minimal/ with `\```{}`?

Comment: RStudio calls the "R Sweave", which seems slightly redundant. "R LaTeX" would be more apt, really, and more parallel with "R Markdown" and "R HTML".

Answer (score 0):

One difference seems to be when using chunk references to reuse chunks, addressed by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40967975/what-is-this-knitr-magic-that-produces-a-plot-by-calling-plot-this) and the [link to the documentation on Reference/Macro](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/), which only makes use of `<<>>` type chunks. Duplicating the example:

```
<<chunk1>>=
1 + 1
@

<<chunk2>>=
<<chunk1>>
@
```

such that the second chunk simply duplicates the code in `chunk1`.

To convert this into back tick chunks, you seem to need to do:

````
```{r chunk1}
1 + 1
```
````

that is, a direct replacement as suggested in my question and Ben Bolker's answer. However, to refer to chunk 1, it seems that **angled brackets are still required**:

````
```{r chunk2}```
<<chunk1>>
```
````

In addition, note that leaving the code as is:

```
<<chunk2>>=
<<chunk1>>
@
```

does not work, at least with respect to `rmarkdown::render` with the file saved with `.Rmd` extension.