# Sweave v. Knitr v. Rmarkdown: code chunk headers

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, sweave

I am trying to understand the relationship between `rmarkdown`, `sweave` and `knitr`. Looking at code and examples I have run into two types of code headers and I don't understand what language/package they belong to.

The headers are

````
```{}
```
````

and

```
<<>>=
@
```

1. What is the difference between them?
2. Ho do they relate to `rmarkdown`, `sweave` and `knitr`?
3. If I work on a `.rnw`, which one am I using?

Comment: `sweave` is based on a LaTeX base-format, `rmarkdown` is based on markdown. Both allow code-chunks for R-code, output, and plots. `knitr` [used to support `sweave`](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/) but apparently no longer does, so it renders `rmarkdown` into one of many output formats (including LaTeX, pdf, html, markdown, docx, epub).

Comment: @r2evans Sorry for confusing you, but **knitr** supported Sweave from Day One, and still supports it. The documentation you mentioned said the full compatibility was dropped, which only means some Sweave chunk options were no longer supported. This `.Rnw` format is still well supported.

Comment: @YihuiXie Wow, Yihui Xie himself! :) I just want to know what the difference between those two headers is. Could you please help?

Comment: @YihuiXie, my apologies, it was a quick scan for the comment, I didn't read it completely (this time). Thanks for correcting my mistake.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the difference is: `\`\`\`{}` is for `rmarkdown`, and `<<>>=` is for `sweave`.

Comment: @r2evans Yeah, I think that's it! So would you say `sweave` is a "language"? If it is not, what is it? Also, at least we got Xie to comment!

Comment: Zweifler, I believe it is more of a markup to "normal LaTeX" that provides code-execution (simply put), however I'm not a pro on `sweave`. I have never really used it, frankly ... I was using R and LaTeX well before I knew about `sweave`, and then jumped directly into `rmarkdown`. There are definitely advantages to using `sweave`, namely the ability to control things in LaTeX that markdown does not support.

Comment: There seems to be a lot  of confusion about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41093706/what-is-the-difference-between-knitr-chunks-and-chunks

Comment: @r2evans Your understanding above is absolutely correct, so please feel free to post an answer. If there's anything that needs to be further clarified, I'll be happy to chime in. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Both sweave and rmarkdown provide the ability to run arbitrary code for R, python, and other programming languages. The pros and cons of each are varied, but a quick comparison:

R markdown :

- typical file extensions: `.rmd` (case-insens), perhaps `.rmarkdown`
- supports R, python, and [several other languages](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/language-engines.html)
- outputs to HTML, docx, LaTeX (and therefore PDF), and [several other output formats](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-options)
- uses the triple-backtick for chunk demarcation

  ````
    Regular text.

    ```{r chunkname, chunkoptions, ...}
    a <- 1
    ```

    ```{python pychunk, chunkoptions, ...}
        def myfun(v: list) -> list:
        """
        Something important in this docstring.
        """
        return [a+1 for a in v]
    ```

    More regular text.
  ````
- because it is based on markdown, there are some limitations for cross-references, table-control, etc; there are packages and known mitigation techniques for many of them (too many to list here). However, you can use direct LaTeX formatting in the markdown, so output to PDF can enjoy that control as well (though LaTeX code is not translated for other output formats).

Sweave:

- typical file extensions include `.rnw` (case-insens) and I've seen `.noweb` (not fully certain on this ...)
- supports R, and perhaps other languages if you can get to them through R (such as via [`reticulate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reticulate/index.html))
- outputs to LaTeX and therefore PDF
- uses `<<>>=` and `@` for chunk demarcation:

  ```
    Regular text.

    <<chunkname, chunkoptions, ...>>=
    a <- 1
    @

    More regular text.
  ```
- because it is based directly on LaTeX, you can as much control over formatting, cross-referencing, etc

`knitr`

- processes files of both `sweave` and `rmarkdown` formats
- some sweave pre-processing may be required (e.g., using `Sweave2knitr`), ref: https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/
- the [rationale for knitr](https://yihui.org/knitr/) is to
  "solve some long-standing problems in Sweave, and combine features in other add-on packages into one package (knitr ≈ Sweave + cacheSweave + pgfSweave + weaver + animation::saveLatex + R2HTML::RweaveHTML + highlight::HighlightWeaveLatex + 0.2 * brew + 0.1 * SweaveListingUtils + more)."